# html table border exists

Tags: html, border, html-table

Hy, i have a little problem, i've set

```
border: none;
border-width: 0px;
border-spacing: 0px;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
```

for table, td and tr, but the 1px border still exists between tr nodes.

Html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href='url'> some text </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href='url'> some text </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

for  i've set

```
display: block;
color: white;
font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none;
height: 24px;
padding: 9px 19px 1px;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
```

changing padding to 0, don't give any results.

Any solutions?

Browser: last chrome, firefox.

OS MAC OS 10.8

Comment: Whether `table` has `cellspacing` specified?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
border-style: none;
```

Note that this doesn't work in some versions of IE. IE9 is fine but in previous versions it displays the border even when the style is "none"

```
border: 0;
```

seems to work in all browsers...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `border-collapse: collapse;` in the table styling and `border-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px;` in the cell.  See example code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <style>
        table {border-collapse: collapse;}
        table tr {}
        table td {border-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>


    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <a href='url'> some text </a>
          </td>
          <td>
             <a href='url'> some text </a>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide your full CSS write-up for the table styling, not just the properties.

Comment: This is all, other properties contain only inherit properties,

Comment: In that case you are not specifying what to apply those properties to... Take the code above, it's tried and tested and works.  If you cannot get it working after using the above CSS then create a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code and I'll take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

i think your code was right?

Is this what you wanna see?

[image: Is this what you want?]

setting

```
border-collapse:collapse;
border:none;
```

is enough..